# How to create a chrome extension with multiple views

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been looking for sometime and cannot find a way to switch between different html views in a chrome extension. I am creating and extension with user log in and want to switch to a profile.html view once the user logs in. I've tried the way below but this just opens a popup window, is there away to do it where it loads the html page into the current extension view? Or is the only way to edit the extension view through javascrip?

```
    chrome.windows.create(
      {
        tabId:      newTab.id,
        type:       "popup",
        url:        chrome.extension.getURL('user_profile.html'),
        focused: true
      }, function(window){
          //
        });
  });
```

Comment: Are you talking about in a browser action?

Comment: Yes, looking for something that would work simliar to chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: 'user_profile.html'}) only the user doesn't have to click off the browser action then back on to see the change @Brian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but the easiest way is to think of it as a single page app.  You don't change views based on user action, you serve up content based on context.

That said there are two ways I have seen this done routinely:

1. Use iFrames.  I am not a huge fann of this one, but if you have existing server side rendered pages, it's the easiest solution.  Essentially, you just make the iFrame take up the size you need, then update the source of it and let the frame navigate as it would need to.
2. Use javascript to serve up desired content.  This is probably the best solution for most situations.  Based on whatever context you have, use javascript templating to update what the user is seeing.  There's too many different (and good) ways to accomplish this to give specific code here, but Googling around should be pretty easy.