# Chrome extension: How to change view upon router.navigate

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, angular2-routing

I'm trying to create a very simple 2-page chrome extension. The first page handles login and the second displays a button that users can click to check-in. Inside the button is a timer letting the user know how much time he has until the next check-in.

Here are my manifest and background pages:

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "...",
"description": "...",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"icons": {
  "16": "assets/favicon-16.png", 
  "128": "assets/favicon-128.png"
},
"background": {
  "page": "index.html",
  "persistent": false
},
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon" : "assets/favicon.ico",
  "default_popup": "index.html#/login"
},
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PROOf of LIFE</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/background.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>

</html>
```

Now on to the problem:

When I click the 'ENTER' button ([prtscrn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1bAF.png)) it calls `login()`, which executes perfectly fine, sending the api call and receiving the response, but when it hits `this.router.navigate(['/check-in']);` the view displays nothing but a small blank square ([prtscrn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdsxG.png)) instead of the html from `check-in.html`... and what's even stranger in my opinion is that I can click that blank square, where the check-in button should be displaying, and it will run the `check-in()` method, effectively writing to the database, which tells me that it did in fact navigate to the router-link that I wanted... but how can the functionality be there and no view be rendered?

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component }         from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm }            from '@angular/forms';
import { UserService }       from '../user-service.service';
import { DataService }       from '../data-service.service';
import { AuthGuard }         from '../auth-guard.service';
import { User }              from '../models/user';
import { Router }            from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})

export class LoginComponent {

  title = 'PROOF of LIFE';
  isRequesting : boolean = false;
  errors : string; 
  userLoginModel: User = {
    email: '',
    pin: '',
  };

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private userService: UserService, private router : Router) {}

  login() {
    this.isRequesting = true;
    this.userService.isRequesting = true;

    let utcOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

    this.userService.login(this.userLoginModel.email, this.userLoginModel.pin, utcOffset, (userInfo) => {

        if (!userInfo) {
            this.errors = 'Email and/or pin is incorrect.';
            this.isRequesting = false;
            this.userService.isRequesting = false;
            return;
        }

        sessionStorage.setItem('authentication_token', userInfo.auth_token);
        sessionStorage.setItem('next_PoL_action', userInfo.next_PoL_action);

      this.dataService.authGetData(`api/users/user?id=${userInfo.id}`, (currentUser) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('current_user', JSON.stringify(currentUser));   
            this.router.navigate(['/check-in']);
            this.isRequesting = false;
            this.userService.isRequesting = false;
      }, (error) => {
        this.isRequesting = false;
        this.userService.isRequesting = false;
        this.errors = error;
        return;
      });
        }, (error) => {
            this.isRequesting = false;
            this.userService.isRequesting = false;
            this.errors = error;
        });
    }

}
```

Here is the **check-in.html** (which should be displaying)

```
<section class="section" id="homepage-section">

  <div class="container">

      <h1 class="header-title">{{ title }}</h1>

      <div *ngIf="errors" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          <strong>NOT OK!</strong> {{errors}}
      </div>

      <div class="pol-button-cont">
          <div (click)="checkIn()" class="pol-button" [class.button-grey]="status == 0" [class.button-blue]="status == 1" [class.button-red]="status == 2" [class.button-black]="status == 3">
            <div *ngIf="checkinTimer > 0 && currentUser.Active != false" class="pol-button-timer">{{ checkinTimer | secondsToTime }}
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="checkinTolerance > 0 && checkinTimer < 0 && currentUser.Active != false" class="pol-button-timer">
                    {{ checkinTolerance | secondsToTime }}
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="currentUser.Active == false" class="pol-button-text-small">
                    inactive
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

I'll be happy to provide any additional information, just let me know what you need. I'm sure I'm just missing something really stupid and basic... Thank you for your help.

[EDIT] I should mention I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042940/how-to-create-a-chrome-extension-with-multiple-views) question but its answer is vague at best and doesn't exactly answer my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by adding a specific `height` and `width` to the `body`. Apparently everything was there, it was just hidden because I did not set the size of the page.